# Maven: testCompile failed multiple points

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

My project has the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oauth-test Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <scribe.version>2.5.2</scribe.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-test.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring-test.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
        <retrofit.version>2.1.0</retrofit.version>      
        <okhttp.version>3.4.1</okhttp.version>

        <kripton.version>3.1.0</kripton.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- scribe -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
            <version>${scribe.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Kripton -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abubusoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>kripton</artifactId>
            <version>${kripton.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abubusoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>kripton-retrofit-converter</artifactId>
            <version>${kripton.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>oauth-test</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.abubusoft</groupId>
                            <artifactId>kripton-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${kripton.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now.. i run command:

```
mvn install
```

And i receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project oauth-test: Execution default-testCompile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile failed: multiple points -> [Help 1]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to clean up your local .m2 repository ?

Comment: I've already tried to delete all .m2 repo, but nothing change

Comment: Try running Maven in verbose mode (`mvn -X -e`) to pinpoint the exact location of the error. It sounds like a `NumberFormatException`, likely coming from the annotation processor

Comment: Can you share your web.xml?

Comment: The web.xml does not matter for maven build.

Comment: At last i found the problem: just remove source and target tag under compiler plugin and it start to work!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally i found the problem. In the compile plugin, i used `${java.version}` to define source level and target level, but i didn't define this placeholder. Just define in properties section

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

And everything works.

Comment: Same problem for me... a result of creating a new maven app with lots of copy/paste from an existing app I was references. Thanks for the help.